# WPF how to get control and TextBlock to align in center in stretched grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following scenario:

```
<Grid x:Uid="Grid_3" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" Focusable="False" Visibility="Visible" Background="DarkGray" Opacity="0.4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition x:Uid="RowDefinition_8" Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition x:Uid="RowDefinition_9" Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <controls:LoadingPanel Grid.Row="0" IsLoading="True"
                           HorizontalLoadingIndicatorAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalLoadingIndicatorAlignment="Center"  
                           />
        <TextBlock x:Uid="TextBlock_4" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Commit In Process..." />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I want the `LoadingPanel` and the `TextBlock` to be aligned in the center of the `Grid` which I have set to be stretched vertically and horizontally.

Note that the grid is already inside another grid. At the moment both places themselves at the top.

Comment: Centered Horizontal and Vertical on the Grid? If yes, then keep in mind you have two rows, and each control is on a row. You can discard the rows if you want them both to be centered Horizontal and Vertical on the Grid.

Comment: Please post a picture how the desired view should look like.

Comment: @LupuSilviu That solved it!

Comment: @LupuSilviu Only problem is that now both the control and TextBlock are placed on top of each other. Can I push the TextBlock below the control ?

Comment: If you do that,  the textblock it will not be visible. Use `Panel.ZIndex="2"` on the LoadingPanel and `Panel.ZIndex="1"` on the TextBlock, like this `<TextBlock Panel.ZIndex="1"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I'm guessing the issue you're seeing is that the controls are not centred vertically but instead sit at the top of the grid?

To resolve this (while keeping the controls below one another) simply add a relative sized row above and below the two rows for the controls like so:

```
<Grid x:Uid="Grid_3" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" Focusable="False" Visibility="Visible" Background="DarkGray" Opacity="0.4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
        <RowDefinition x:Uid="RowDefinition_8" Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition x:Uid="RowDefinition_9" Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <controls:LoadingPanel Grid.Row="1" IsLoading="True"
                       HorizontalLoadingIndicatorAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalLoadingIndicatorAlignment="Center"  
                       />
    <TextBlock x:Uid="TextBlock_4" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Commit In Process..." />
</Grid>
```

This should sort out the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be able to give an answer to this topic, I am reposting the comment from above, to allow @DSF to accept it.

Apparently the issue was related to the fact that the grid had two rows, and each control was on it`s own row. Discarding the rows solved his issue.

To fix the order of visibility, as you want, use Panel.ZIndex="2" on the LoadingPanel and Panel.ZIndex="1" on the TextBlock, like this